# Not able to install mongodb on ubuntu 20

Tags: software-installation, mongodb

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apturl-common chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1
  gstreamer1.0-vaapi libapache2-mod-php7.4 libboost-program-options1.71.0
  libextutils-depends-perl libfwupdplugin1 libgoogle-perftools4
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4
  libyaml-cpp0.6 libzip5 mongodb-server-core php7.4 php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli
  php7.4-common php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline python3-dateutil
  python3-debconf update-notifier-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos
  mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/49.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 242 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 226106 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mongodb-org-shell_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (6.0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mongodb-org-server_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (6.0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-TzKvpS/1-mongodb-org-server_6.0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (6.0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-TzKvpS/2-mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (6.0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-database.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mongodb-org-database_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-database (6.0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mongodb-org-tools_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (6.0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mongodb-org_6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (6.0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-TzKvpS/1-mongodb-org-server_6.0.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-TzKvpS/2-mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried many times i am getting error while installing mongodb on my ubuntu machine
please be nice to me i am very new to ubuntu

Comment: Your pastes aren't from a 20 system, they more correctly match a 20.04 system which is a different Ubuntu product (the *year* format and *year.month* formats used highlight different products; ie. 20 & 20.04 are different systems).  Please re-check your question & details.    (fyi: there is no `apt`, `apt-get` or `dpkg` command is 20 but your paste relates to *deb* packages 20 cannot use)

Comment: Could you also post the command you used?